# Root and other accounts using more file descriptions than what ulimit is configured with

Tags: java, process, linux-kernel, file-descriptor, ulimit

Now I under this question has been asked before, but everyone seems to show the soft limit.  My concern is around how a process has more file descriptors (fd) than what the hard limit has, and what does that mean for performance?

Based on other online articles the hard limit is just that, a hard ceiling, so that would mean a crash if hit?

I should add that now the system hasn't crashed, and currently is running relatively okay.  I'm just looking to see about making performance improvements, and benefits to software that's been around for 15 years.

### Configuration

This is a web server running JAVA passing data to postgresql from other devices.

```
]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
20854863

]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
43320   0       20854863
```

Ran the su command just to show this is for the root account.

```
]# su - root -c "ulimit -Hn -Hu"
open files                      (-n) 4096
max user processes              (-u) 819554
```

### Analysis

Root is running 923 process

```
]# lsof -u root | awk '{ print$2 }' | uniq -c | wc -l
923
```

Of that there is one process that has way more fd than configured

```
]# lsof -u root | awk '{ print$2 }' | uniq -c | 
...
10823 2550
...
]# ls -l /proc/2550/fd/ | wc -l
10675
```

So based on configuration we can have a lot more processes than open files, but not seeing the system us this.  We also have another user, company specific name, and it has the same problem.  Hard limit is 4096 but it's sitting at 13112 open files for one process.

We have since increased this for the company specific to 16000, but yet to change root as I am looking to under stand what is going on.

### Questions

How is the system using more fd than what the hard limit is configured with?

For the forking process, is this done by the system or the application you are writing?  In the case of our software it seems that java is happy to run under one process, if it has enough fd.

If we compare this with the postgres service, postgres is happily spinning more processes once it hits the soft limit, or just needs to do other things.

```
]# lsof -u postgres | awk '{ print$2 }' | uniq -c
      1 PID
    678 1064
    741 1067
    766 1131
    561 1446
    681 1447
   1034 36122
    912 54028
    951 54195
   1026 56139
... about a dozen more records
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out problem is related to "Left hand doesn't know what right hand is doing".  Seems one team was setting limits from system level, but other team was doing it from config files in `/etc/default/jetty`.  Depending on if jetty was triggered from interactive shell or non-interactive shell depended on which settings it was using.

So in other words.  The limit was higher because the limit in `/etc/default/jetty` was set higher than system.